# Send a file over sockets QT

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to send a data file over sockets with Q++ but the server receive an empty data stream, can you help me ?

```
QFile file("/Users/mathieu/Documents/test.wav");
if(!file.exists()) qDebug() << "not found file";
file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
QByteArray data;
data.append(file.readAll());
file.close();
QUdpSocket udpsock;
udpsock.writeDatagram(data, QHostAddress::Any, 1441);
```

And for the receiver:

```
QUdpSocket udp;
QByteArray buffer;
buffer.resize(udp.pendingDatagramSize());
QHostAddress sender;
qint16 senderPort;
udp.readDatagram(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
qDebug() << buffer;
```

But buffer is empty... I don't understand why.

Comment: Doesn't look like you're hooking up the udp socket receiver to a port?

Comment: Is your receiver's code in the slot function for the signal `readyRead()`? Also, you have to check if you have any incoming datagrams: `while(udp.hasPendingDatagrams()) {...` And your socket should be bound with the port: `udp.bind(1441,QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to init your receiver UDP Socket.

```
void initUdp() {
    udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    udpSocket->bind(udpPort, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);
    connect(udpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(processUdpData()));
}

void processUdpData() {
     while (udpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
          QByteArray buffer;
          buffer.resize(udpSocket->pendingDatagramSize());
          udpSocket->readDatagram(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
          qDebug() << buffer;
     }
}
```